# ListPlot: individual point colors

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I've got a simple ListPlot like

```
list2 = Table[{x, Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, 100}];
```

Now I want to color specific points with RED, say every 5th point, I tried

```
mycolor[x_] /; Mod[x, 5] == 0 = Red;
mycolor[_] = Blue;
```

Now

```
ListPlot[#, PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[3], ColorFunction -> 
mycolor[#[[All, 1]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False]] &[list2]
```

doesnt work quite right, all points are still blue.
What is wrong here?

Thanks,
archi

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1300/listplot-with-each-point-a-different-color-and-a-legend-bar

Answer (score 3):

Here is an easy way to get the result you're after :-

```
list2 = Table[{x, Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, 100}];
mycolor[x_] := If[Mod[x, 5] == 0, Red, Blue];
mycolors = mycolor /@ list2[[All, 1]];
ListPlot[List /@ list2,
 PlotStyle -> Map[{AbsolutePointSize[3], #} &, mycolors]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, with a colour function, thanks to [rm -rf's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1327/363) on george's link :-

```
list2 = Table[{x, Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, 100}];
mycolor = Function[{x, y}, If[Mod[x, 5] == 0, Red, Blue]];
ListLinePlot[list2,
  PlotStyle -> AbsolutePointSize[3], ColorFunction -> mycolor, 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> False] /. Line -> Point
```

**Further to comment**

For different plot markers I have reverted to the easy method.  In order to apply different styles and plot markers in ListPlot the differently styled points have to be in separate lists, hence `List /@ list2`.  (Only two lists would actually be necessary though.)

```
Clear[mycolor];
list2 = Table[{x, Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, 100}];
mycolor[x_] := If[Mod[x, 5] == 0,
   {Red, "\[FilledUpTriangle]", 14},
   {Blue, "\[FilledSmallCircle]", 6}];
mycolorspec = mycolor /@ First /@ list2;
ListPlot[List /@ list2,
 PlotMarkers -> Apply[Style[#2, FontSize -> #3, #1] &,
   mycolorspec, {1}]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Chris! The first solution look rather cryptic to me ;)
    mycolors = mycolor /@ list2[[All, 1]];
maps to all elements in list2 with the Mod condition. But why is there
    List /@ list2 ?


I played around with ColorFunction first, but did not get through. Seems the trick ist List[Line]Plot in place of ListPlot and then tell him to draw points with /. Line -> Point...

Comment: One more Q: How can I give to all the red points another PlotMarker, say, "FilledUpTriange"?
Thx,
archi

Comment: @archipelago - re. ListLinePlot, yes, as [rm -rf points out](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1327/363) ListPlot on its own does not pick up the colour function.